# Can “not…either” be used in a interrogative sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

Can “not…either” be used in a interrogative sentence?
Does this sentence “Do you not like coffee either?” sound natural to you?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

If the person you are speaking to has just expressed a dislike of something that would normally be grouped with coffee, then yes, that sentence would be perfectly fine:

> "Would you like some tea?"
>
> "Tea!  Blech!  Can't stand the stuff.  Why anybody would want to take perfectly good water and pollute it with bits of dead vegetation is beyond me."
>
> "I see.  Do you not like coffee either?"
>
> "Oh, I can't live without my coffee.  One cream, no sugar, please."